# How do you control the width of a ModernUI dialog?

Tags: wpf, dialog, modern-ui

We've got a user control we're written that's meant to fit both on a window (works fine there) and now within a class I've defined which inherits from ModernUI ModernDialog. The user control I'm trying to place on the ModernDialog derived class is wider than the ModernDialog allows for. I've tried setting the Width property of the derived ModernDialog class both within the class itself and within the code that calls the class. The ModernDialog box consistently ignores all attempts I've made to control the ModernDialog's width.

Why is it doing that?

How do I control the width of the ModernDialog?

Comment: Even implementing the Loaded event for the class and specifying a Width there, is useless. The ModernUI's ModernDialog just dictatorially ignores anything you specify and uses what it want to use. So I'm back to asking is there a way over specify the width of a ModernDialog and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the width of a ModernUI dialog. It has a hard coded maximum and minimum width. Between these lengths the dialog will size to its content.